# com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type JSON

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a code here.. this is the

**main_menu.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        getData();
    }

private void getData(){
        String url = config.DATA_URL+a_username;
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        Log.d(TAG,"MERGING URL AND NAME SUCCESS");
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                showJSON(response);
                Log.d(TAG,"SHOW JSON SUCCESS");
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
private void showJSON(String response){

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject userid = result.getJSONObject(0);
            id = userid.getString(config.KEY_ID).toString().trim();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG,"GETTING ID SUCCESS");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void  onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        real_id = id.toString();
        mref = new Firebase("https://connection-4f6d8.firebaseio.com/"+real_id);
        mref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                if(text.equals("UNLOCKED")){
                    sendDataonWIfi("0");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**Execption:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.jaypeetan.mftis, PID: 32112com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
at com.example.jaypeetan.mftis.main_menu$6.onDataChange(main_menu.java:290)
at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:56)
at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)                     at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@22c79a40; line: 1, column: 1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:46)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)                                                                                     ... 13 more
```

I do believe the error is about the JSON
what I need is the user ID in my database which is im getting correctly but the problem is when I tried to connect in my firebase it giving me this error.. I tried to change the variable ***real_id*** value into number and it is working properly but when it depends on the JSON it gives me an error.. please help me :D

**this is the snapchat of my firebase**
[image]

Comment: real_id is int or string?

Comment: it is a  String the same as id

Comment: why not you use the new firebase quires?

Comment: what do you mean by quires?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this [new updated Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data).

Import .JSON file to the android project and then try to get data like this

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mPostReference.child(real_id).addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

Comment: may i know where did you get the Post? do i need to declare that?

Comment: post is actually data class you are getting from server, you can just define post class and one string there in the class with the same name which you are getting from file base and getter and setter function for that string.

Comment: may i know how to define that post class?? please help me i really wanted to finish this im just new into this android studio and JSON

Comment: please share your firebase snap so i am able to help u completely

Comment: do you mean is the screenshot of the firebase??

Comment: all you can do is get the list of that data and than do whatever you want to do with that list

Comment: uhhmm... actually I didnt get that exactly but i will explain it more so that we can understand each other more on this :D .. I have a database with username and password with ID when a user login his user and pass the android will get the user's ID and that ID will be I be using on my variable.. the thing is.. I get successfully the ID but it doesnt work properly on the name of my firebase

Comment: get the full list of your data and than compare locally to get desired data

Answer (score 0):

You store a mix of `String` an numbers in the same list. Then in your code you always ask for a string:

```
// THIS FAILS WHEN THE SNAPSHOT VALUE IS A NUMBER
String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

That won't work, since a number is not a string (even though it can be converted to one).

If you insist on mixing types, your code that extracts the value must be able to handle the mixed types. For example:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String text = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
```

By using `dataSnapshot.getValue()` without a type, we will get whatever type is stored in the snapshot. We then convert it to a string with `String.valueOf()`.

I recommend however sticking to a single uniform type in a list. It'll make your code less error prone and easier to understand.

Comment: I tried to change your answer.. i tried to change the numbers into condition, condition1, condition2, condition3... now the problem this is my new syntax mref = new Firebase ("https://connection-4f6d8.firebaseio.com/condition"+real_id);... now the problem is.. the thing that changing is child "condition" not the child "condition"+real_id